# Sort by taxonomy weight

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type 'Member' with a field referring to taxonomy term called 'Member role' which is a multi value field. Each member may have up to 3 member roles.

I have created a view to display members which sorted by taxonomy term weight with reference to taxonomy field. But the problem is each member repeats 3 times in the view result page.

My question is how to remove duplicates and only sort by last value in the multi value field(Member role).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are a couple of things you can try to reduce duplicates caused by a multi-value field. Results will vary depending on your particular view.

#### 1. Use aggregation

Under "Other" in Advanced options, enable *Use aggregation*.

Locate the offending field under "Sort criteria". Click on *Aggregration settings*, then select **Aggregation type:** *Maximum*.

#### 2. Filter by delta

Under "Filter criteria", add the delta equivalent of your multi-value field; e.g. if your field is "field_artist_bio", there should be another field available called "field_artist_bio:delta".

Add the field. Set **Operator:** *is equal to*, **Value:** *0*.

Comment: Thank you. Aggregation with minimum for the aggregation type work for me.

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear it.